# Isolate URLs from other text around it and put each on own line (with sed)

Tags: regex, bash, url, shell, sed

I have a small shell script that uses `sed` to take an input file of URLs with hand-written notes around them and strips the notes and puts each URL on its own line.  For example:

INPUT:

```
note: http://www.example.com/Beat-Poetry + ??? http://www.example.com/beat+poetry
http://www.example.com/17th+cent. + http://www.example.com/17th+century + http://www.example.com/17th+c.
http://www.example.com/18th+century
https://www.example.com/C19th-C20th + http://www.example.com/19th-20th+century (note)
note:
http://www.example.com/18th+cent. note http://www.example.com/18th+century
```

**Note:** the URLs will always either have leading/trailing space or start or end the line.

DESIRED OUTPUT:

```
http://www.example.com/Beat-Poetry
http://www.example.com/beat+poetry
http://www.example.com/17th+cent.
http://www.example.com/17th+century
http://www.example.com/17th+c.
http://www.example.com/18th+century
http://www.example.com/C19th-C20th
http://www.example.com/19th-20th+century
http://www.example.com/18th+cent.
http://www.example.com/18th+century
```

I have this code, which does the job by adding some delimiters around each URL and removing stuff based on where the delimiters are found, but I am a newbie with this stuff, and it doesn't quite feel right.  If nothing else, it's not robust enough to withstand potential usage of `á` and `é` characters in the "notes".

```
#!/bin/bash

  # squash out all the extra text that isn't URL (notes to self) and put each URL on a new line
  # hackish steps to achieve this:
  # - change urls from http://url to áhttp://urlé
  # - put each one on a new line
  # - remove leading space/words
  # - remove trailing space/words
  # - change any https to http

sed -re 's/(https?:[^ ]*)( |$)/á\1é /g' \
     -e 's/é[^á]*á/\n/g' \
     -e 's/(^[^á]*)(á[^é]*é)/\2/g' \
     -e 's/é[^á]*$//' \
     -e 's/https:/http:/g' $1 |
tr -d 'áé\r' |
sed -rn 's/(http:\/\/www.example.com\/.*)$/\1/p'
```

**I assume that there is a more proper way to do this?** (Again, the URLs will always have whitespace or `^` or `$` around them.)  I'd appreciate any improvement suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: Why are you replacing `https:` with `http:`?

Comment: Probably should have just left that line out of the question, as it's just for not having to deal with the differences later in another script (though I appreciate you including it in your answer).

Answer (score 4):

What about this?

```
cat input | tr ' ' '\n' | grep -i "^http"
```

1. Put every string on new line.
2. Filter urls.

Comment: Yowzers, so much cleaner than what I had. I knew I was overthinking it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is essentially a word-splitting problem — something that Bash is actually quite good at doing, using only built-in commands.  You certainly don't need to go insert and then strip out `á` and `é` as marker characters.

```
while read line ; do
    for word in $line ; do
        case "$word" in http*) echo ${word/#https:/http:} ;; esac
    done
done
```

Comment: This one took my newbie brain a little longer to wrap my head around (and also my machine ... it looks like it's a bit slower than Jan's script ... 10 second vs. 2 seconds for nearly 25000 lines, but who's counting?), but kudos for making it all-`bash`, since IIRC cygwin required me to explicitly install `tr` and `grep`.